# Imperative mode advantages

Tags: glue42

Documentation points to [declarative](https://docs.glue42.com/g4e/net-interop/index.html#interop-declarative_model) and [imperative](https://docs.glue42.com/g4e/net-interop/index.html#interop-imperative_model) model for method interop, with the **imperative** one seemingly being the advanced one.

What are the benefits of using one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

The declarative model is created upon the imperative one to make your project easier to understand, therefore, easier to maintain.

The only case the imperative one could be useful is if someone wants to manually manipulate the data exchanged in the interop, ignoring the type safety the Glue42 .NET SDK provides.